# Make static route data available on NavigationStart in Angular Router

Tags: angular

The parent component of my application renders a router outlet, along with a navigation item like so that I'd like to conditionally hide:

```
<nav *ngIf="hideNav"></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I would like to make it so when a designated route starts loading, ie `misc` in the example below, `hideNavigation` gets passed along from the data object (or something else similar to this) to inform the parent component when to hide the nav element.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: (): Promise<typeof Module> =>
            import('./views/home-page/home-page.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'misc',
        data: {
            hideNavigation: true
        },
        loadChildren: (): Promise<typeof Module> =>
            import('./views/misc/misc.module').then(m => m.MiscPageModule)
    }
]
```

I know this can be done on `NavigationEnd` to pull data from a nested route like so:

```
this.router.events
    .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        startWith(this.route),
        map(() => this.route.snapshot),
        map(route => {
            while (route.firstChild) {
                route = route.firstChild;
            }
            return route;
        })
    )
    .subscribe((route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
        this.hideNav = route.data.hideNavigation;
});
```

But is there a better way to handle things like this so I can get *static data* on `NavigationStart` as opposed to `NavigationEnd`? One thing to note is that I need this to work if a user hits the url directly and when they do not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to go about this IS to subscribe to the NavigationStart router event, as you've shown in your example. I, however, do not fully understand why and exactly what for you need all of those function calls in `pipe`. I tried the following in my Angular app:

```
    this.router.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart && this.navHidingRoutes.includes(event.url))))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.hideNav = true;
        });
```

This worked like a charm. As long as all you need to do is something simple like setting a boolean value or calling a method in the parent component, this approach should suit your needs.

Comment: The example in the post was a subscribe call that pulls data off of a nested route.data object.

While what you provided would technically work, is there a way to pull something directly off of the route object as opposed to manually maintaining a list of navigation items that require this element to be hidden? The ultimate goal here is to store route specific things alongside the route vs maintaing a list seperately.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pull something directly from the route object, no... I could be wrong, though. If you do eventually find out that this is not possible, or not possible in the way you expected it to be, you could do something like storing the routes array separately from the routing module, use this array in the routing module, and also define a filter-mapper function that finds all routes with a `data: {hideNavigation: true}` field in this array and returns the array of the URLs of such routes, that can then be used in the root app component.